# How to specify Xpath that return whole table without last row?

Tags: xpath, html-table, extract

Here is the code of a table. I need to extract whole table without last row.

Whole table:

```
 <table class="product-content__table">
    <tr><th class="product-content__th">Состав</th><td>нержавеющая сталь, натуральная кожа </td></tr>
    <tr><th class="product-content__th">Ширина</th><td>2 см</td></tr><tr><th class="product-content__th">Цвет</th><td>серый </td></tr>
    <tr><th class="product-content__th">Страна производства</th><td>Россия </td></tr><tr><th class="product-content__th">Сезон</th><td>Мульти </td></tr>
    <tr><th class="product-content__th">Коллекция</th><td>Весна-лето </td></tr>
    <tr><th class="product-content__th">Артикул</th><td itemprop="sku">RO003DMCMA98</td></tr>
    </table>
```

I need to extract whole table without this row:

```
<tr><th class="product-content__th">Артикул</th><td itemprop="sku">RO003DMCMA98</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<td>` is sibling of `<th>` not child so you don't actually need `th` in your xpath. And you want to filter out the last `tr` within the same `table` instead of filtering out the last `td` within the same `tr` :

```
//table[@class="product-content__table"]//tr[position() < last()]/td
```

<sub>remove trailing `/td` if you want to get list of `<tr>` instead of `<td>`.</sub>

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. Everything works but i received tr and th tags only....I need all tags including table tag. I am parsing whole table because i need this html formatting. Xpath you specified return data I need but they are not enclosed in table tag. How to fix it?

Comment: Hi @AndreyRadik you're trying to return modified version of the HTML and I'm afraid xpath isn't the right to tool to achieve that. xpath as far as I can see is natural for finding specific part of HTML/XML and return that part the way it is in the original doc.

Comment: @AndreyRadik Expert happen to be in my side :) (see Michael Kay's answer)

Answer (score 2):

> I need all tags including table tag.

XPath can only select nodes that are present in your input. If there is a table element in your input with five rows, and you want a table element with four rows, then there is no such table element in your input so you cannot select it with XPath. If you want to get a node that differs from any node in your input, you need XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
//table//tr[position()<last()]
```