# How to concatenate string and xpath attribute node?

Tags: string, xpath, concatenation

Using Xpath, I want to concatenate this string: "/images/products/"

and values of **url** attribute from this hmtl:

```
<div id="small-images">
<ul>
   <li url="1.jpeg"></li>
   <li url="2.jpeg"></li>
   <li url="3.jpeg"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So, I want to get result like this:

```
/images/products/1.jpeg
/images/products/2.jpeg
/images/products/3.jpeg
```

I tried this way:

```
concat(//div[@id='small-images']//li/@url, '/images/products/')
```

Not working.

How to concatenate string and value of **url** attribute?

Comment: Which language are you hosting xpath in? You'd have to iterate on `li` elements and use `concat()`.

Comment: You'll need something more than just xpath. Remember the conclusion when you asked about [returning table without the last row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861062/how-to-specify-xpath-that-return-whole-table-without-last-row)